# SageMaker Data Parallel error: smdistributed.dataparallel DDP does not support broadcast_buffers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am running the code below using SMDDP, and encountering the error `SageMaker Data Parallel error: smdistributed.dataparallel DDP does not support broadcast_buffers`

Full source code: https://gist.github.com/joshualat/64bb1b32f1e6dcc9f25cd265e3fc0b30

```
...

import smdistributed.dataparallel.torch.distributed as dist
from smdistributed.dataparallel.torch.parallel.distributed import DistributedDataParallel as DDP

...


if __name__ == "__main__":

    ...

    model = models.segmentation.deeplabv3_mobilenet_v3_large(
        pretrained=False,
        progress=False,
        num_classes=args.classes)

    model = DDP(model)

    model.train()


    amp = True

    CE = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr, momentum=args.momentum)
    scaler = GradScaler(enabled=amp)


    ...
```

Thoughts on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by SageMaker Distributed Data Parallel so you need to set `DDP(model, broadcast_buffers=False)`